# Creating Netbeans Code Template for tinylog

Tags: netbeans, syntax, code-templates

I am attempting to add a code template to Netbeans so that typing lg followed by Tab will insert a tinylog statement.  What I have so far is:

```
Logger.${logLevel type="org.pmw.tinylog.Logger.*" editable="true" default="info" }("${message}");
```

This works somewhat and produces a line that looks like:

```
Logger.info("message");
```

Pressing Tab moves the cursor between 'info' and 'message'.  I can modify the 'message' field, press Tab and move back to the 'info' field.  However, if I hit Control-Space and change 'info' to any of the other methods, the new method loads, but the code template wizard shuts down and then Tab just moves code to the right instead of switching between the method name and String parameter.

Have I made an error in my template, or am I asking too much from Netbeans to expect it is possible to keep the wizard alive when I change methods from info(String) to debug(String) for instance?